# Execute a switch case only once with keeping the order of enum in C# in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, switch-statement

I have this enum:

```
public enum Stat
{
    x,
    y,
    z,
    a,   
}
```

I am using another enum for roles:

```
public enum Role
{
    [Display(Name = "student")]
    student,
    [Display(Name = "teacher")]
    teacher,    
    [Display(Name = "employee")]
    employee,
}
```

In my controller, I have this code:

```
switch (table?.Type, table?.Stat)
{
    case (Role.student, Stat.x):
    case (Role.teacher, Stat.y):
    case (Role.employee, Stat.z):
        var stat4 = new model()
                        {
                            Stat = VM.stat,
                            Type = Role.student,
                            FormId = form.Id
                        };
        _context.table.Add(stat4);
        break;

    case (Role.teacher, Stat.a):
        TempData["error-message"] = Message = "error";
        break;                          

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In my controller in the edit `POST` method, I want to execute every case once and the order have to be (x,y,z,a), so when a teacher set y he cant set x anymore and go on.

I am struggling to make the switch statement case only execute once its not working and am new to ASP.NET Core MVC world, can someone help me please?

```
bool caseExecuted = false;

switch (table?.Type, table?.Stat)
{
    if (!caseExecuted)
    {
       caseExecuted = true;

       case (Role.student, Stat.x):
       case (Role.teacher, Stat.y):
       case (Role.employee, Stat.z):
           var stat4 = new model()
                           {
                               Stat = VM.stat,
                               Type = Role.student,
                               FormId = form.Id
                           };
           _context.table.Add(stat4);
           break;

       case (Role.teacher, Stat.a):
           TempData["error-message"] = Message = "error";
           break;                           

       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

I tried doing this but it execute no matter how many times

Comment: is there some kind of loop in your method? Or the method is called multiple times? How can you confirm that `caseExecuted` is not reset back to `false` in subsequent calls? And what does "the order of enums" have to do with your question?

Comment: That sounds like you need a state machine, not (only) a switch-case.

Comment: items in stat `x/y/z` can execute this endpoint and then becomes `a`, and `a` cannot execute this endpoint - is this explanation for your requirement correct?

Comment: @Felix there is no loop I was just confused about how to prevent changing the stat after setting it to a specific value

Comment: @Fildor can you explain more please?

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang correct but I want to prevent any change as no one can change y to x but they can change y to z and so on

Comment: If there is no loop - how is the code called afterwards? just another call? then `bool caseExecuted = false;` and nothing prevents changing the stat. You may want  to rethink what you are trying to do, and ask the question again. Or maybe, once you rethink, - you will figure out the answer yourself. That would be the best result!

Comment: So you need to first get the current state. Then you can decide if the requested new state is allowed or not and respectively save it to db or not. That's a state machine.

Comment: Don't have time to write answer for now, but mainly you can use `(int)` to cast enum into int, for instance `(int)VM.Stat`. You can then check `if ((int)VM.Stat < (int?)table?.Stat)`, assuming table means entity from database. If your `enum Stat` is always ordered in `x,y,z,a`, then it'll promise that `a`'s int value always is the largest. I think that's enough for you to work out the rest.

Comment: @Felix you were right I didn't need caseExecuted  it was my mistake

Comment: @Fildor great I searched it and I will try it out Thnaks

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang Exactly!! I will try doing it Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @XiangWeiHuang it worked !!
the idea was to compare the enum as *int* and I didn't think of that before.

*so here is the answer if someone needs it in the future*

```
switch (table?.Type, (int)table?.Stat)
{
    case (Role.student, (int)Stat.x):
    case (Role.teacher, (int)Stat.y):
    case (Role.employee, (int)Stat.z):
        if ((int)VM.stat < (int?)table?.Stat)
        {
            var stat4 = new model()
            {
                Stat = VM.stat,
                Type = Role.student,
                FormId = form.Id
            };
            _context.table.Add(stat4);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["error-message"] = Message = "you can't change back status");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        break;
    case (Role.teacher, Stat.a):
        TempData["error-message"] = Message = "error";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```